# ruby arrays and handling matching items

Tags: ruby

I am running a ruby script right now which executes an action based on a specific type of filtering.

Its a system that purges assets older than 90 days.  I've created a new query that looks for members of a exception group.

I cannot figure out at all how to handle checking if the old_assets array member is a group of the Ignore_assets member and if they do match skip that one asset and do not delete it.

```
 puts 'Logged into Nexpose'
 at_exit { nsc.logout }

 ignore_assets = Nexpose::AssetGroup.load(nsc, 30).devices.each do |device|
     puts "Asset ID to be Ignored: #{device.id}"
 end

 puts "Searching for Assets to Delete"
 old_assets = nsc.filter(Search::Field::SCAN_DATE, Search::Operator::EARLIER_THAN, '90')
 old_assets.each do |asset|
     nsc.delete_asset(asset.id)  
     puts ("Asset ID to be Deleted: #{asset.id}")
 end

 puts "Assets have been deleted."
```

EDIT:  **I have to match it by device.id because of the way the assets are defined. See below**

```
 Asset ID to be Ignored: 8773
 #<Nexpose::Device:0x3a28358>

 Asset ID to be Deleted: 8773
 #<Nexpose::FilteredAsset:0x3a287a8>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
old_assets.each do |asset|
  next if ignore_assets.map(&:id).include?(asset.id)
  ...
end
```